# how to calculate the number of a rating in a data frame

Tags: r

suppose I have a data frame consist of 60 columns and 170 observations. The rating for each of the 60 variables is from 1-7. Now I want to calculate how many "5" are there in the data frame, how should I do that using R?

Comment: Try `sum(df == 5)`, but consider to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Or try `table(as.vector(as.matrix(df)))`

Comment: thanks, that second answer works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> df <- sample(1:7, 10200, replace=TRUE) %>% 
+     matrix(nc = 60, nr = 170)
> 
> df %>% .[df == 5] %>% plyr::count()
  x freq
1 5 137
```